# o.respond_to?(:empty?) and o.empty? Fails with: "undefined method `empty?`"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so how is that possible?

I have a Module, that puts a Ruby Object at the end of the renderd page in a nice structured HTML. So i recurse through the given object and build the HTML output. The following is an excerpt of the code where the error is thrown.

EDIT:(had a copy error in code)

```
o=some object
nicer=if o.respond_to?(:empty?) and o.empty?
    add_class='empty'
    'empty ' + class_name
else
    case o
       when TrueClass then
    "TRUE"
       when FalseClass then
    "FALSE"
       when Array
#some more when's
```

the error thrown: `undefined method 'empty?' for #Journey::Routes:0x123456`
the object (o) it self is `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet`

again: how is that possible?

EDIT: Stack: (there is the bad one ...)

```
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:366:in `empty?'
lib/tech_draw.rb:90:in `format_nice'
lib/tech_draw.rb:101:in `block in format_nice'
lib/tech_draw.rb:100:in `each'
lib/tech_draw.rb:100:in `map'
lib/tech_draw.rb:100:in `format_nice'
lib/tech_draw.rb:124:in `block in format_nice'
lib/tech_draw.rb:123:in `map'
lib/tech_draw.rb:123:in `format_nice'
lib/tech_draw.rb:13:in `block in say'
lib/tech_draw.rb:13:in `map'
lib/tech_draw.rb:13:in `say'
lib/tech_draw.rb:13:in `map'
lib/tech_draw.rb:6:in `say'
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:131:in `any_page'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
...
```

Comment: Are you sure error came from that part, which you are showing us.. I think it came from some where else..

Comment: yes, sure, i changed `respond_to?(:empty?)` to `respond_to?(:empty_foo?)`-> no error (and never "empty class") I filter this out with Exception handling

Comment: see the full error stack please

Comment: I put in edited quesstion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is that possible? Easy:

```
class Thing
  def respond_to? *args
    true
  end
end

o = Thing.new

o.respond_to?(:empty?) and o.empty?

# => NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for #<Thing:0x00000100ae2558>
```

Although why is it happening in this case is another matter.

[`ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#empty?` appears to call `empty?` on  `routes` object](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L365-L367). Assuming this object is an instance of `Journey::Routes` that would explain the error, as [`Journey::Routes` doesn’t have an `empty?` method](https://github.com/rails/journey/blob/v1.0.4/lib/journey/routes.rb). (In current Rails versions Journey is part of Rails itself, but in Rails 3.2 it is separate).

I don’t why this is happening in your case though.

Comment: as the message says; `#Journey::Routes` does not have an `empty?`, and `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` uses 'it' without checking ... I understood now.